# How to get yellow out of sink surface?

Tags: bathroom, stain

It’s not real marble I don’t think but the yellow stains are gross looking — this is a rental apt pls help

[image]

<sup>Click for full size</sup>

Comment: I can't see yellow stains.

Comment: Try some toothpaste on a hidden section.  Just the toothpaste and a soft cloth and rub.

Comment: magic eraser can work quite well, test on hidden section first.

Comment: Did _you_ make the yellow stain? If so what with? If not (especially if you just moved in), ask the landlord to address it.

Comment: i've inlined a version with a slight colour-punch to make the staining more obvious.

Comment: @Tetsujin, Thanks , now i can see it.

Answer (score 0):

Whether it's plastic or enamelled steel, you can try, in this order…

- Generic 'bathroom cleaner' liquid spray - anything that claims 'total cleaning', soap scum, limescale, etc.
- Actual dedicated spray de-scaler [kitchen/bathroom, not kettle/coffee maker].
- Regular household [chlorine] bleach.
- More expensive [& less likely to work] 'oxygen' bleach.

Leave each of these, if necessary re-wetting the surface, for an hour or more, as this is not just your regular bi-weekly 'mother-in-law' clean.

& then very gently, testing each first on a less-conspicuous area…
Any of these could scratch or dull the surface, hence the pre-test each time.

- any squeezy bottle 'paste' type bathroom cleaner. [Cif is a common EU one. idk for other territories]
- melamine block [magic eraser]
- Barkeeper's Friend
- Any product containing 'orange oil'.

& because it's already been mentioned in comments

- toothpaste. [Depending on which type, this could be either innocuous or very abrasive.]